# Active Record join with params in condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am not sure I know the best way to write this sql query in active record without totally writing it by hand. Essentially I want to write a combination of these two queries.

This query is essentially the join I am trying to re-create. I want to make sure any entries returned are only those with the images with a image_path_processing flag set to false.

```
@entries = ContestEntry.joins(:entry_images).where(contest_id: @contest.id, entry_images: {
        image_path_processing: false
        }).limit(10)
```

However the issue I am running into with the query I am writing is that I need to include params from a url and I am not sure that the above syntax is properly removing sql_injection

Here is what I am attempting to add the conditional join to.

```
@entries = ContestEntry.where("contest_id = ? and created_at > ?",
      params[:contest_id], Time.at(params[:after].to_i + 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
@entries = ContestEntry.joins(:entry_images).
                        where(contest_id: params[:contest_id],
                              entry_images: { image_path_processing: false }).
                        where('contest_entries.created_at > ?', Time.at(params[:after].to_i+1)).
                        limit(10)
```

Comment: This is close I had to add contest_entries. to created_at > so it new what table to preform the check on the correct table. contest_entries.created_at

Comment: I knew it! Ahah, I'm glad that my solution helped you!

Comment: Thank you Yoshi you saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

First, read this documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Back in the day, the primary supported syntax was

```
ContestEntry.where("contest_id = ?", params[:contest_id])
```

but now you can also use the simpler and more ruby-ish

```
ContestEntry.where(:contest_id => params[:contest_id])
```

Both of these approaches will pass the params through a sql sanitizer to prevent sql-injection attacks as described in the documentation.

A couple additional points:

1. I am not sure how to implement that latter syntax for anything but equality.
2. The problems you've heard recently regarding sql injection, do not apply to the syntax you are using.  They apply to dynamic finders.

Finally, you shouldn't take my word for it.  One of the best pieces of advice a ruby developer ever gave to me was *'Use irb to learn ruby'*.  If you have a question about how something works, load up irb and test it.  In your case you are implementing rails, so you have the full console at your disposal.

```
sql_injection_params = "anything' OR 'x'='x"
# This string variant tells active record to use sql as is 
Model.where("name = '#{sql_injection_params}'").to_sql # bad
# This array variant tells active record to sanitize
Model.where('name = ?', sql_injection_params).to_sql # good
# This hash variant tells active record to sanitize
Model.where(:name => sql_injection_params).to_sql # good
```

The `to_sql` call will show you what raw SQL active record builds based on your query.  Just change the above example to use your data and you should get a better idea of what rails is doing under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on sql injection. The current discussion is a bit confusing :).

Answer (score 0):

```
@entries = ContestEntry.where("contest_id = ? and created_at > ?",
      params[:contest_id], Time.at(params[:after].to_i + 1))
```

seems perfect way to avoid the sql injection from the user entered result...